# Using autocomplete feature in AVR Studio for coding C with avr-gcc

Tags: arduino, avr, atmel, avr-studio4, avr-studio5

How can I enable or disable the autocomplete feature for the IDE [AVR-Studio 5](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/avr_studio_5/default.asp?source=redirect) or [AVR-Studio 4](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=2725)? Do I have to edit some installation files to do this?

In the video [AVR Studio 5: How to use the Editor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsammK3FfEg&feature=player_embedded), the man uses a supposed autocomplete feature (without entering ctrl+enter) on AVR Studio 5. But I looked for it on google and [Atmel](http://www.atmel.com/) site, and could not find.

Comment: [Ensuing meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113073/i-believe-my-question-should-not-have-been-closed-how-can-i-get-it-re-opened) (which lead to the question being reopened, after it had been closed). Closers: note that AVR Studio is an IDE, autocomplete is a feature that is mostly of interest to programmers, so this question fits squarely in the “software tools commonly used by programmers” bullet point of the [faq].

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Gilles. I tried to improve the question to minimize the doubts.

Comment: [Also posted at the AVR forum](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=894127)

Comment: I don't see any problem in asking here in SO if I don't get the answer from AVR forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AVR Studio 5 select the VAssistX menu and click on 'Enable/Disable Visual Assist X".  This should turn on and off the feature.

Comment: I'm surprised that I didn't wonder that VAssistX could mean this. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's not the most obvious naming convention :)